# Why Azure CLI login fails? "Connection actively refused"

Tags: proxy, windows-10, azure-cli

Using azure CLI for the first time on windows 10,  In command line I type: `az login`, which takes me to browser to choose user account.  Selecting my name takes me to screen saying
"You have logged into Microsoft Azure!"  However, about 30 seconds or so later my command line spits out:

`Please ensure you have network connection. Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common/oauth2/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x045270B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))`

A lot of the feedback online centers around linux distros and proxy issues.  None of the suggested fixes have worked so far.  Could this be a cert issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `--debug` at the end of the script to know the full error trace.
This error indicates Azure CLI is not able to connect to AAD server and `login.microsoftonline.com` at port 443. It is blocked by NSG or firewall. Please unblock `login.microsoftonline.com` which is required to get an access token and check whether the port is not used.